# Where to download jdk 1.4.2 for Windows

Tags: java, download, jdk1.4

From where can I download Sun JDK 1.4.2 for Windows. I have checked Sun's website and since they have stopped the support to this version it is no longer available for download.

Comment: Stopped support for over a year.  It ran out in Oct 2008, if I recall correctly.  Even JDK 5 is reaching the the end of its life.  Why on earth do you think you need it?

Comment: @duffymo: JDK5 has already been EOL'd, as of October 30 this year.

Comment: Duffymo, that's a bit of an overly-judgy question; there are enough easily-conceived-of reasons someone would need an old JDK (having to support a legacy app on a legacy platform, having to perform forensic analysis of a historic app, etc)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Steps to find it:

1. Google ["download jdk 1.4.2 for windows"](http://www.google.com/search?q=download+jdk+1.4.2+for+windows)
2. Visit one of the first hits: [Oracle Java Archive](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html).
3. Read the warning, twice, and follow the link to the [Java SE 1.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html) area.

There you can find several archived 1.4.2 downloads, the currently latest for Windows being [1.4.2_19](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase14-419411.html#j2sdk-1.4.2_19-oth-JPR).

Comment: It looks like the newest version offered for windows at the location above is Java SE Development Kit 1.4.2_19. All versions above that (up to 30 which is the last release) are for Solaris.

Comment: @Jooky: at Dec 29, 2009, that page looked entirely different.

Comment: It appears the last release of 1.4.2 for Windows is Java SE Development Kit 1.4.2_19. Go to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html, Java SE 1.4, then search for "windows".

Answer (score 0):

At sun homepage.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/download.html

Comment: It requires to register on Oracle site now and it really frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link to Sun's Archive which includes every point release for all JDK/JRE

http://java.sun.com/products/archive/